# Using Webdeploy with Webmatrix (Orchard)

Tags: iis, webmatrix, webdeploy

I have setup a VM (VMWEB-3) to test local development of Orchard CMS using Webmatrix and the deploying to web server.

I have installed IIS 7 on VMWEB-3 (Server 2008) and downloaded and installed (Default) WebDeploy2.

I add the settings in WebMatrix:

Server: vmweb-3
User: vmweb\Administrator
password: *********
site name: Test
Url: .http://vmweb-3

I keep getting connection timeout when I validate. I can browse to .http://vmeweb-3 and get the IIS 7 splash etc

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something that sorted it out ... I had not done all of the IIS configuration. Here is the article I used to fix the issue:

[Webdeploy IIS Configuration](http://blogs.iis.net/krolson/archive/2009/11/04/using-iis-manager-accounts-for-web-deployment-tool-msdeploy-delegation.aspx)